# Wordpress on Mac does not load admin page

Tags: local-installation

Homepage loads just fine, but I cannot log into the admin page. Looking in Chrome developer tools I notice that

```
/wordpress/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5B%5D=hoverIntent,common,admin-bar,wp-ajax-response,jquery-color,wp-lists,quicktags,jquery-query,admin-comments,jquery-ui-core,jquery-&load%5B%5D=ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,jquery-ui-sortable,postbox,dashboard,customize-base,customize-loader,thickbox,plugin-install,underscor&load%5B%5D=e,shortcode,media-upload,svg-painter,heartbeat,wp-auth-check,word-count,wplink&ver=4.0
```

and

```
/wordpress/wp-admin/load-styles.php?c=0&dir=ltr&load=dashicons,admin-bar,wp-admin,buttons,wp-auth-check&ver=4.0
```

*never* load. I've waited about 5 minutes, but they hang.

Comment: Hey can you Activate the `WP_DEBUG`? And see if there is any errors there?

Comment: ever have a resolution on this?

Comment: Was the issue solved?